# Define a Class with global functions in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make an app in iPhone since i am new so i require a little info over this matter.

I have few classes

```
Class 1
Class 2
Class 3
...
Class 10
```

I have a new NSObject Class "Utilities". In this class i want to define some functions like

let's say, pass a NSMutableDictonary and calculate average

```
-(void) calculateAvg:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
-(void) calculateMile:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
-(void) calculateAnythingElse:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
```

Now these are the functions that will be used in entire app classes, from 1 to 10. Instead of Putting these functions in each class i have made this Utilities Function. 
In java i could do this

```
Utilities newUtil = new Utilties();
newUtil.callFunction();
```

However How can I do this in my iPhone, i am a bit confused if this is the work of Singleton set? Or i should use regular method by

```
Utilities newUtil = [Utilties alloc] init];
```

Then calling functions.

Now that this class will be used again and again in entire app classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with below steps:

1) Create NSObject Class "Utilities", which you have done.

2) Add all methods which you want it as global. But with "+" instead of "-" like below:

```
+(void) calculateAvg:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
+(void) calculateMile:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
+(void) calculateAnythingElse:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
```

3) Import "Utilities.h" class first in ".pch" file.

4) That's it. Done.

You can access all above methods throughout the app like below:

```
[Utilities calculateAvg:<dictionary_object>];
```

Means, no need to create object. You can access static methods by class name only.

Hope you got an idea.

Happy Coding!

Cheers!

Comment: #ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Utilities.h"
#endif ?

Comment: I can't call NSMutableDictonary in NSObject.

Comment: Not getting you. You only need to pass dic object to method.

Answer (score 1):

Just make those utility methods *class methods*:

```
+(void) calculateAvg:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
+(void) calculateMile:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
+(void) calculateAnythingElse:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic
```

Which will work as long as they don't require instance variables to operate on.  They can then  be used like this:

```
[Utilties callFunction];
```

Note that a singleton is not involved here; a singleton is an instance of a class that can optionally contain instance variables and only a single instance can exist.  What you are looking for is a class with class methods which effectively makes them the same as C-functions as they don't require instance variables and are simply a way of grouping such functions into a single manageable unit.

Comment: Thanks i got it, when i will define these in my .m file it will be simple +(void) calculateAvg:(NSMutableDictonary *)myDic { //Code here}?